# Python / Pandas / Pulp Optimization Duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, pulp

I am trying to optimize a grouping / selection of trial members with limited space, and am running into some trouble. I have the pandas data frames ready for optimization, and can run the linear optimization with no problems, except for one constraint I need to add. I am trying to use binaries for selection (but I am not tied to that for any reason, so if a different method would resolve this, I could switch) from a large list. I need to minimize combined trial time for selection in the next round of trials, but some subjects already ran multiple trials due to the nature of the experiment. I would like to select the best combination of subjects based on minimizing time, but allow some subjects to be in the list multiple times for the optimization (so I do not have to manually remove them beforehand). For instance:

```
Name         Trial    ID       Time (ms)    Selected?
Mary Smith   A        11001    33           1
John Doe     A        11002    24           0
James Smith  B        11003    52           0
Stacey Doe   A        11004    21           1
John Doe     B        11002    19           1
```

Is there some way to allow 2 John Doe entries for the optimization but constrain the output to only one selection of him? Thanks for your time!

Comment: You don't have to 'manually' remove them. You could just `df.sort_values(['Name', 'Time (ms)']).drop_duplicates('Name')` and you're left with the shortest time for each person.

Comment: Right, sorry I guess I should have clarified that. Due to the nature of the trials and the data set, I would need to record the removal of each trial, so even though I could drop the poor scores, I'd have to make a record of that by hand, which would be extremely time-consuming. So I think I am mostly bound to this format in pulp.

Comment: Here's how I'd do it in `pulp`: Using pandas I'd identify each duplicated subject (Joe Doe.) For each such subject, you need to add one 0/1 (binary) variable. Finally, add a SOS (specially ordered set) of these variables, one constraint per duplicated subject. `y_JD1 + y_JD2 <= 1` to force the output to be at most one of this subject.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a requirement to record all the values you want to remove, you could use the `duplicated` function, like this

```
# First sort your dataframe
df.sort_values(['Name', 'Time (ms)'], inplace=True)

# Make a new column of duplicated values based only on name
df['duplicated'] = df.duplicated(subset=['Name'])

# You can then access the duplicates, but still have a log of the rejects
df.query('not duplicated')
#           Name Trial     ID  Time (ms)  Selected?  duplicated
# 2  James Smith     B  11003         52          0       False
# 1     John Doe     A  11002         24          0       False
# 0   Mary Smith     A  11001         33          1       False
# 3   Stacey Doe     A  11004         21          1       False

df.query('duplicated')
#        Name Trial     ID  Time (ms)  Selected?  duplicated
# 4  John Doe     B  11002         19          1        True
```